# PayPal Express Checkout

Tags: paypal, payment

Is it necessary to have a confirm page after returning from PayPal with token and PayerID? Or there is no problem in calling directly **DoExpressCheckoutPayment** without showing confirm page to buyer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the useraction=commit variable in your SetExpressCheckout API call.  The purpose of "useraction=commit" is to allow you to finalize the transaction automatically, immediately when the buyer returns, instead of offering them one more confirmation screen.  You would do this in a scenario where you don't need to do things such as calculating shipping charges based on the address returned from GetExpressCheckoutDetails, and you are sure the original payment amount is the final amount.